# Life cycle endorsement with "Any Majority" in Fabric 2:0 is not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Chain code life cycle endorsement is not working when following changes made in configtx.yaml.

```
LifecycleEndorsement:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
Endorsement:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
```

Network contains:

- one ordering service cluster with five orderers running Raft
- three organizations (Org1, Org2 and Org3), each of which has one peer (peer0)
- one channel mychannel is created, and peers in all organizations join the channel

Package SACC into chaincode package

- Install chaincode package to peers of all the three organizations
- Org1 approves chaincode package, and tries to commit the chaincode. It fails and getting Endorsement policy error.

But chain code should be commited as LifecycleEndorsement has "Any Endorsement" rule.